# Select returns the same row multiple times

Tags: sql

I have the following problem:

In DB, I have two tables. The value from one column in the first table  can appear in two different columns in the second one.

So, the configuration is as follows:

TABLE_A: Column Print_group
TABLE _B: Columns Print_digital and Print_offset

The value from the different rows and Print_group column of the Table_A can appear in one row of the Table_B but in different column.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table_A 
INNER JOIN  B ON (Table_A. Print_digital = Table_B.Print_group OR 
Table_A.Print_offset = Table_B.Print_group)
```

The problem is that this query returns the same row from the Table_A two times.

What I am doing wrong? What is the right query?

Thank you for your help

Comment: joins can do that. can you show example data?

Comment: If you join table A to table B and table B has more columns, often it will duplicate the row from table A each time it joins B. In this case, would you rather the duplicate rows were blank from table A?

Comment: So, let's say that the Print_group column of the Table_A has the values 1 on the first row and 2 on the second one. In the Table_B is only one row (to keep it simple for now). The Print_digital column of the Table_B contains the value 1 from the first row of the Table_A and the Print_offset column of the Table_B contains the value 2 (the values are on the same row of  the Table_B). Running the above mentioned query returns resultset containing two rows - it is one row of the Table_B returned two times...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need the row from the Table B is returned only one time...so the resultset will contain only one row after running the query...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to clarify your fields to come from `Table_A`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM Table_A A 
    INNER JOIN B ON A.Print_digital = B.Print_group
        OR A.Print_offset = B.Print_group
```

***EDIT:***

Given your comments, looks like you just need `SELECT DISTINCT B.*`

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.* 
FROM Table_A A 
    INNER JOIN B ON A.Print_digital = B.Print_group
        OR A.Print_offset = B.Print_group
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll give it a try in the afternoon and let you know the result :-)

Comment: Wow!!! :-) Thank you once more! It is exactly what I needed. It works like a charm!

Comment: @user2852877 -- np, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I've still another question... first,to be clear, the right query version is

SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM Table_A A 
    INNER JOIN B ON A.Print_digital = B.Print_group
        OR A.Print_offset = B.Print_group.

If I want it returns also one column from the B table it again returns duplicate rows. My query (the bad one) is the following one:

SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.Id 
FROM Table_A A 
    INNER JOIN B ON A.Print_digital = B.Print_group
        OR A.Print_offset = B.Print_group